# hp nvidia quadro pro p2000 not detected by motherboard (msi Z270 gaming pro carbon)

Tags: motherboard, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-quadro

I have a [msi Z270 gaming pro carbon motherboard](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/Z270-GAMING-PRO-CARBON.html) with corsair rm850x power supply, intel core i7 7770K cpu, two Corsair Vengeance LPX 32Go (2x16Go) DDR4 3000MHz C15 XMP 2.0 and a Samsung 960 EVO Disque Flash SSD NVMe (on which I installed windows 10 pro 64 bits). My motherboard detects without any problem my EVGA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti Jeu SC2 Gaming, 11 Go GDDR5X graphic card (put in PCIe slot 1) but doesn't detect at all a hp nvidia quadro pro p2000 plugged in the second PCIe slot. Is there something special I am missing, or does the quadro probably have a problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a second EVGA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti instead of the quadro and it was detected --> I think the quadro is faulty, will return it to the seller.